# boost::scoped_ptr documentation inconsistency?

Tags: c++, boost, smart-pointers

[`boost::scoped_ptr` documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.htm) contains an example of a technique referred as Handle/Body Idiom. It is described there in the following words:

> The scoped_ptr_example_test.cpp  sample program includes a header file,
>   scoped_ptr_example.hpp, which uses a **scoped_ptr<> to an incomplete type** 
>   to hide the implementation.

However, at the same time, in the [documentation for `checked_delete`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/utility/checked_delete.html) it is stated:

> A particularly troublesome case is when a smart pointer's destructor, such as
>   **boost::scoped_ptr::~scoped_ptr, is instantiated with an incomplete type**.
>   This can often lead to silent, hard to track failures.
>   The supplied function and class templates can be used to prevent these problems, as they
>   require a complete type, and cause a compilation error otherwise.

`scoped_ptr` indeed uses `checked_delete` in its implementation. To me it looks like the two passages contradict one another. Also, I fail to compile my code that tries to employ the proposed trick with the following message:

```
checked_delete.hpp:32: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to 
incomplete type 'MyClass'
```

So is, indeed, the documentation of `scoped_ptr` erronous or do I just miss something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They don't contradict each other. Because `scoped_ptr` is a template, and because there is no explicit instantiation in the code, each method is instantiated on demand. That means that the type must be complete by the time that `~scoped_ptr<>` is instantiated, which in this case is in the .cpp file after the held type is complete (look for `example::~example(){}` close to the end of the file, which is where `~scoped_ptr<>` is instantiated)

This is actually an interesting use case for a user defined destructor that looks exactly the same as the compiler generated would, but allows you to control *where* / *when* the destruction happens to enable the PIMPL pattern with some smart pointers. If the destructor was not declared and defined, then the destructor would be implicitly defined by the compiler where needed, and the type would be incomplete, causing UB.

Comment: Actually both destructor and constructor must be user defined. If the compiler generated default constructor is used, then the compiler will try to instantiate the `scoped_ptr` in `main()`, where the type is incomplete.

Comment: Actually, there is no such issue with `shared_ptr` because it uses type erasure to create a deleter object that is instanciated in the constructor. FYI it is completely possible to use a `shared_ptr` to an incomplete type in a class and only define a constructor for this class.

Comment: @FireAphis: The constructor need not be user defined. Instantiation of the `scope_ptr` template does not mean that the destructor of `scope_ptr` is instantiated, only those methods that are used are instantiated, and I don't think that it is undefined to use the constructor on an incomplete type (it only passes/stores a pointer, which is fine for incomplete types) --that is, assuming that the constructor did not dynamically allocate the type, where an incomplete type is again a problem.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Correct, I seem to recall having to do that with some old implementation of `shared_ptr`, or maybe it was actually with `scoped_ptr` too long ago to remember. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez: I could not compile without an empty constructor. The compiler complained about the undefined type inside scope_ptr's destructor. Is there a different explanation?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas "_I don't think that it is undefined to use the constructor on an incomplete type_" can you give an example?

Comment: @curiousguy: Consider `std::auto_ptr`, you can create one with an incomplete contained type, what is UB is to have its destructor called when the type is still incomplete.

Answer (score 2):

A member function of a class template is only instantiated where it is
used.  The only place `boost::scoped_ptr::~scoped_ptr` is used in ins
the destructor of `example`.  Which is defined in
`scoped_ptr_example.cpp`, after the definition of
`example::implementation` is complete.  The function
`boost::checked_delete` is designed so that it will not compile if the
type is incomplete; `boost::scoped_ptr::~scoped_ptr` uses this so that
the code will not compile if you try to invoke it in a context where the
type is not complete.

(FWIW: using `boost::scoped_ptr` in the pimpl idiom is a bit overkill, 
and not very useful; since you have to provide a user defined destructor
anyway, it really doesn't buy you much, and adds a small bit of
complexity.)

Comment: "_using `boost::scoped_ptr` in the pimpl idiom is a bit overkill, and not very useful_" It is clear, self-documenting, and a good habit to use `scoped_ptr` to express exclusive ownership.

Comment: @curiousguy `scoped_ptr` really doesn't buy you much in the pimpl idiom, since you still have to implement the destructor.  I can understand the argument concerning documentation of intent, but if the class contains exactly one pointer, named `myImpl`, or something like that, and with a type `Impl`, I'd say that the intent is more than clear; you've gone beyond expressing exclusive ownership, and made clear the actual pattern being used.

Comment: I agree with most of your comment. But I think that there is a case to be made for uniformity: where exclusive ownership is involved, use `scoped_ptr` if possible. (But I won't mind if you don't.)